# How to fix png image edges in GIMP?

Tags: image, photoshop, gimp, graphical-logo

I am designing a logo for my business and I need to fix the edges of my image. (As you can see they are not straight lines).

I have installed GIMP because I am trying to do this for free and can't seem to fix this problem. I am very new to editing images.

Any way I can fix this image? Or maybe someone could do it easily for me for free?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8emYc.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do logos the best tool for that is a "[vector graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics)" editor (for free: [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), for Adobe: illustrator). Vector graphics can be scaled up properly (because it seems that your logo has been scaled up...)

If you want to pursue with bitmap graphics, the best way is to erase the lines and redo them properly:

- Use [guides](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-image-guides.html) (the dashed vertical/horizontal lines) to "prepare" the positions and make sure that everything is square and symmetrical
- Create [paths](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-paths.html) (the blue-whote lines) using these guides to indicate where lines are going to be
- Render the lines by "stroking" the paths in `Line` mode.
- Create a last path for the red bits (that are the corners of a square)
- Bucket-fill the red square
- Make a rectangle selection (easy using the existing guides) and delete the center (no need to be too accurate since the "inner grid" will hide the excess.
- Transfer VH by copy/paste

Note that each element is on its own layer, makes everything a lot easier.

[image]

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH @xenoid this saved me hours of extra work :)

Comment: yup, thanks for reminding me and now I feel a lot more confident with GIMP 